# Make the image smaller which is added as content of my view's layer

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, rect

I want to set an image as my view's content but I don't want the image to take the whole frame. I want the image to be smaller. To achieve that I am trying to set the contentsRect to be 80% of the main layer.

```
 self.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "plus")?.cgImage
 self.layer.contentsRect = self.layer.frame.insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 5)
```

But this doesn't work. When I debugged, I realized, the layer's frame is

```
▿ (256.0, 398.0, 100.0, 100.0)
```

and the contectsRect is

```
▿ (261.0, 403.0, 90.0, 90.0)
```

[image]

But it still didn't solve the problem, meaning the image is not getting smaller. Can anyone tell me how to fix the issue.

Comment: You’re  barking up the wrong tree. That is completely not what the contents rect is or how it works. Forget about the whole approach and describe what effect you wish to achieve.

Comment: I am programmatically trying to set an image on a view's layer but I want to make the image smaller, not take the whole frame.

Comment: Then draw the image smaller to start with. By the way stop saying frame. That’s part of your problem. The layer’s frame is irrelevant. Every time you say frame you should be saying bounds.

Comment: How do you expect inset of 5 will lead to 80% ? With global size of 100, that leads logically to 90%. Is the image effectively 90% with your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach.

- subclass `UIView`
- add an "image" `CALayer` as a sublayer
- in `layoutSubviews()` set the image layer's content and frame (or, add your own function to set the image and layer content)

Example code:

```
class Image80View: UIView {
    
    let imgLayer = CALayer()
    var img: UIImage?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        layer.addSublayer(imgLayer)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let img = self.img {
            imgLayer.contents = img.cgImage
        }
        // 10% on each side, so 80% of view
        imgLayer.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: bounds.width * 0.1, dy: bounds.height * 0.1)
    }
    
}

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let testView = Image80View()
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let img = UIImage(named: "plus") {
            testView.img = img
        }

        view.addSubview(testView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor),
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])

        // so we see the view's frame
        testView.backgroundColor = .green
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was setting the layer's contentsRect rather than its frame.